# Java zip utility not writing into C:\

Tags: java, windows, zip

I've been using this code to compress a directory into disk C, in the university lab's computers the program did create the exp.zip without any problems, but it was impossible in my computer. I changed disk C ownerships to my actual session, with all privileges allowed, and ran the program ( a .jar file ) as administrator without success. I think it is not a code issue cause it worked both in the lab's computers running windows and in linux (changing paths of course) but still I'm going to paste it here so you can have an idea of what i'm trying to do:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;

import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Compress {


public static void zipDirectory(String dir, String zipfile)
  throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {

    File d = new File(dir);
    if (!d.isDirectory())
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not directory:  "+ dir);
    String[] entries = d.list();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;

    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipfile));

    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        File f = new File(d, entries[i]);
        if (f.isDirectory())
            continue;
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f); 
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(f.getPath());
        out.putNextEntry(entry); 
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        in.close(); 
     }
    out.close();
}






  public static void compress() throws IOException {
      String from = "C:\\exp\\"; //path windows
      File f = new File(from);
      if(!f.exists())
      f.mkdir();
      Compress.zipDirectory(from, "C:\\exp.zip"); //path windows


   }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you receive any kind of message?

Comment: What is the error that you got..?

Comment: No, I have some dialogues that confirm me if the compression worked or failed, besides that, I'm not getting any SO message nor anything. In the lab's windows/linux computers I get the success messages and everything works properly so I think it is something with my computer's permissions or something